# Derivation of the Takeoff equation

Tags: takeoff, lift

I am trying to understand the derivation of some simple equations to calculate the neccecary takeoff speed for an airplane (under ideal conditions).

[image]

Which is taken from [15. Takeoff and Landing](http://www.dept.aoe.vt.edu/~lutze/AOE3104/takeoff&landing.pdf). My main issue is the derivation of the horizontal equation

To get from the first to the second line my guess is that we use

```
R = W - L   and    m = W / g
```

My main problem is understanding the details between what happens from line `2-3` and `3-4`. I would love if someone could give me a brief explenation of the symbols used, what does `S` denote?

Comment: What don't you understand from 2-3? It's just rearranging the algebraic terms. #4 replaces lift and drag with the lift and drag coefficients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want to reduce (or simplify) equation 2, to get get dV/dt by itself, so we multiply both sides by g/W.  On the right hand side, this reduces to dV/dt.
On the left hand side it reduces to what is given in equation 3, but let me show you how:
 1. First term is T x g/W
 2. Second term is -D x g/W
 3. Third term is -u x g/W (W - L).  By the distributive property, we have -[u x g/W x W] + [u g/W x L]. The first part of this term simplifies to u x g.

Finally, I want to group like terms together.

1. The first term combined with the first part of the third term give me: T x g/W - ug = g(T/w - u).
2. The second term combined with the second part of the third term give me: -D x g/W + u g/W L = g/W(u L - D).

This yields equation 3: g(T/w - u) + g/W(u L - D) = dV/dt.

Finally, recall that L = 1/2 p S V<sup>2</sup> Cl, with a similar equation for Drag, and we can substitute these directly into L and D to get equation 4.

S is the the wing planform area. Other sources use A, like this one: [NASA - Lift equation](https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/airplane/lifteq.html).